# Check for page hit with PHP and MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, ip

Say, I have an article page (`example.com/article.php?id=1`) that contains news, I want to add this page's data (my data name in the database is `pagehit`). So for every unique IP address that visit this page, the `pagehit` in the database is added by 1.

So far, I've known that using K, we can get the ip address of the client. But how to check that for each unique ip, the `pagehit` in the database can be added?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

probably easiest to either parse the server logs which would have already similar info but what I would recommend is using a table visits with columns

- id - autoincrement
- ip - ip address of visitor
- id - page id
- add additional data you want to collect such as time, etc

on each visit, insert a new record with an sql statement something similar to the following:

```
INSERT INTO visits (ip, id) VALUES ($ip, $pageid);
```

later, you can query the statistics

- count ip visits:
  SELECT count(ip);
- count visits to each page
  select count(id);

you could obviously have more fancy queries such as number of visits per ip to each page etc as well as track many other variables

Answer (score 1):

For checking if a unique ip has visited it or not, You would have to store each unique users IP address in the database also... Or else, you can set a cookie for each user, and then increment the counter or not.

I would recommend using something readily available, like Google Analytics.

Comment: thanks, but I want to check for EVERY different article page for the count. So if article 1 was visited by 192.168.1.1 the count will go up by 1 for that article, and if 192.168.1.1 visited article 2, the count will still go up. Maybe I should check Google Analytics you mentioned, thanks again

Comment: Entreprise proxies can cause side effects. Many different users use the same proxy.